# How can add child nodes in TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TreeView in 3 layers, my TreeView loads me from sql a visual studio through a `recursive function`, but I can't make it save me in the database, it keeps me in the view because I can see the node with its name but when closing the application it disappears, and it is because it is not being saved in the database, can you tell me if I have the function `Insert Nodes` from my `Data layer` wrong?

data layer:

```
              public void InsertarNodos(datostreeview parameters)
              {
                comandSql.Connection = con.AbrirConexion();
                comandSql.CommandText = "sp_InsertNodes";
                comandSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", parametros.Code);
                comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", parametros.Name);
                comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cod_long", parametros.Cod_long);
                comandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idfather", parametros.Idfather);

                comandSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comandSql.Parameters.Clear();
                con.CCerraConexion();
            }
```

domain layer

```
            public void InsertarAttr(string code, string name, string cod_long, int idfather)
             {
                obje_cdtreeview.Code = code;
                obje_cdtreeview.Name = name;
                obje_cdtreeview.Cod_long = Convert.ToInt32(cod_long);
                obje_cdtreeview.Idfather = idfather;
            }
```

presentation layer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (editar == false)
            {
                try
                {
                if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "")
                {
                    nodoSeleccionado = treeView1.SelectedNode;
                    father = int.Parse(dataTableNodos.Rows[int.Parse(nodoSeleccionado.Tag.ToString())]["IdPCuentas"].ToString());

                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ".";
                    string Code = textBox1.Text;
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.ToUpper();
                    string Name = textBox2.Text;
                    textBox3.Text = Codigo.Replace(".", "");
                    string Codlong = textBox3.Text;

                    objc_treeview.InsertarAttr(Cod, Name, Codlong, father);


                    MessageBox.Show("Register Save");                 

                    textBox1.Enabled = false;
                    textBox2.Enabled = false;


                    TreeNode nodoInsertado = new TreeNode();                    
                    nodoInsertado.Text = Code + "  " + Name;
                    nodoInsertado.Name = Code;
                    nodoSeleccionado.Nodes.Add(nodoInsertado);

                }
```

Comment: Where do you call insertaeNodos function

Comment: `objc_treeview.InsertarAttr(Cod, Name, Codlong, father);`